# Is there any way to hide/encode or protect an ajax call?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc, google-chrome-devtools

I'm currently learning Asp.Net MVC (I come from a WebForms background) and I'm implementing Ajax requests to call controller methods that return Json objects. But the problem I'm facing right know is when I want to perform certain actions until user has reached some stage, for example appending an aditional text input, adding a save button, creating a new option list, the problem is that when the user is authenticated I can
perform the ajax call from the developer console (e.g. Google Chrome) and get or sent the json object needed for that specific method, even if the method has the [Authorize] Attribute (When the user is properly logged) and AntiForgeryToken is set, with a little knowledge of jQuery, MVC and a look to the Network tab (In Chrome), I can fake that the call was performed because of the user action I allowed from code rather that it was made from console (I tested myself and It worked). I know I need to perform double side validation, client and server side. This is not a problem when the validations are not many, but when the number increases, making this could be tedious.

Is there any way to make safer ajax calls, like encoding or hiding, or according to your knowledge what is the best practice when making these requests. I'd be pleased with web resources or books where I can get proper info about the topic (I searched but didn't find anything that was clear or specific about my question, I might be searching the wrong way)

Thanks.

Comment: what are you asking ?  are you trying to ask if there is a way to allow ajax calls from code , but block them if they were typed in manually in the console?

Comment: @Scott Selby - Yes, something like that.

Comment: you will never be able to do that , if the user of the website has permission for the controller in question - then any ajax calls made from the console will have the same session and same cookies and will be granted the same permissions

Answer (score 0):

The [AuthorizeAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) as an additional, optional parameter [Roles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.roles(v=vs.118).aspx)

> Gets or sets the user roles that are authorized to access the controller or action method.

One option is to assign a special role to a user when they should be able to reach certain controller actions (via Ajax or otherwise), and control access with the Roles parameter.

Another option is to just perform your own check in the controller to see if that user has met whichever criteria you deem necessary to access the action, and return an error if not.

**UPDATE**

> Is there any way to make safer ajax calls, like encoding or hiding, or according to your knowledge what is the best practice when making these requests.

You can never trust a client application.  That is much more true for web client applications, since the tools to manipulate the client (browser) are so powerful and easy to use.  There is absolutely nothing you can do to prevent someone from using the console to fire off an Ajax command for which they have valid credentials.

Comment: I know I need to do server side check but the problem is when the user fakes the request from console and he/she is authenticated and validations could be many.

Comment: You cannot "fake" a request for which you do not already have sufficient permissions from your website.  If your website does already grant sufficient permissions, then why are you worried about the Console case?

Comment: What I mean is when the user is allowed but the validations could be many like, is the user authorized?, is that option valid?, is that input allowed?, is that check option permitted?, is that comment correct?, validations that can be made client side to make him/her understand what his allowed to do, but can be time consuming making them twice, client and server side

Comment: It might help if you state the concrete problem that you are trying to solve.  This is something that most web developers don't spend time worrying about.  If there's something particular about your case, you may get a better answer if we understand why you need to do this.

Answer (score 0):

you will never be able to do that , if the user of the website has permission for the controller in question - then any ajax calls made from the console will have the same session and same cookies and will be granted the same permissions –

what you could do is add some long annoying token to every ajax call as an extra authentication , but then again the user can just go and watch the ajax traffic and copy and paste that token into their ajax call.

Comment: So the best thing is to make tech savvy user life harder by adding layer like protection tokens to my ajax calls, hopping he doesn't get how they properly work.

Comment: @jecarfor: That will not help.  If they have already observed what a valid request looks like (using the network trace available in any browser), they can just fire off the same request from the console, or from their own app for that matter.

Comment: no-  that is not what I am saying at all ,   if a user is allowed to an action - then they are allowed to that action it is that simple ,  if you are worried that they will call that action too many times then you can protect against the number of times it has been called , but I can't imagine a situation where that will be necessary

Answer (score -1):

Ajax calls is a bit tricky to make secure. Tokens will help to stop cross-domain requests. But the same user can access others info using the same call. A good technique is to use asp.net identity claims-based authorisation or simply do checks in your controller for the user and the related data. If that user does not have a relationship to the data he/ she is requesting then throw an exception.

JK.